# How to add a class to the parent div?

Tags: jquery, class, parent

I want to show an active menu item, based on the active URL. I have a menu as in the HTML below. I want that if a menu item is clicked, the class `active` will be added to the `.menu_mainitem` element.

```
<div class='row' id='main-items'>
  <div class='menu_mainitem'>
    <a href='https://URL.com/index.php?cat=1' class='click-menu'>1</a>
  </div>
  <div class='menu_mainitem'>
    <a href='https://URL.com/index.php?cat=2' class='click-menu'>1</a>
  </div>
  <div class='menu_mainitem'>
    <a href='https://URL.com/index.php?cat=3' class='click-menu'>1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var current = $(location).attr('href');

$('#main-items a').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
    $this.addClass('active'); 
  }
});
```

Unfortunately this will add the `active` class `.click-menu` but I want to add the class to `.menu_mainitem`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `parent()` or `closest('.menu_mainitem')` to get the div you require. My preference is for the latter it is more robust.

```js
var current = $(location).attr('href');

$('#main-items a').each(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
    $this.closest('.menu_mainitem').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Also note that you can make the logic a little more succinct by selecting the `.menu_mainitem` elements directly using `toggleClass()` with a function to determine if the `href` of the child `a` matches your requirements.

```
var current = $(location).attr('href');

$('.menu_mainitem').toggleClass('active', function() {
  return $(this).find('a').attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1;
});
```